Arguments in ROS2 callback function
I want to create subscribers from a topic list, and therefor have to use a common callback
I found the Lambda example for creating a common callback, but the issue is that the argument that ends up getting passed to the callback is equal to the last created subscriber.
self.topicsToRecord.append(["/test_topic1", "std_msgs.msg.String"])
self.topicsToRecord.append(["/test_topic2", "std_msgs.msg.Int8"])
self.topicsToRecord.append(["/test_topic3", "std_msgs.msg.Bool"])

def create_subscribers(self):
        for topic in self.topicsToRecord:
            topicName = topic[0]
            topicType = topic[1]
            self.get_logger().info(f'Creating subscriber {topicName} -> {topicType}')
            
            self.create_subscription(eval(topicType), topicName, lambda msg: 


self.test_callback(msg, topicName), 10)
    def test_callback(self, msg, argument):
        self.get_logger().info(f"Received message on topic {argument}: {msg}")

If i send a message it get this result
[INFO] [1712869540.873230632] [rosbag_recorder]: Received message on topic /test_topic3: std_msgs.msg.String(data='test')

Which to me appears that the last created callback gets the argument passed (/test_topic1 passes "/test_topic3")

I can't give you a direct answer, but since you are implementing a rosbag recorder, you might want to have a look at this. Helped me when doing something similar in cpp and humble.
